# Css Dropdown Button in a navbar

Tags: html, css

Okay so I'm trying to learn CSS and I'm trying to insert a dropdown button in a navbar.

What's happening is that when I hover the button the whole navbar is expanding instead of only the content of the button. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left:8%;
  margin-right: 8%;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

.right{
  float: right;
}


li a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #6f6f6f;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

p {
  color: red;
  margin-left: 8%;
  margin-right: 8%;
}

body{
  font-family:Arial;
  background-color:#f9f9f9;
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  color: #6f6f6f;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
  right: 0;
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 10px;   
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  right: 0;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #e0e0e0}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  right:0;
}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="/"><img src="../../static/image/logoRect.png" width="25"> </a></li>
  <li><a href="/movies">Movies</a></li>
  <li><a class="right" href="">Search</a></li>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Links 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <li><a class="right" href="#about">Explore</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: can you put in a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify a height and remove the overflow hidden.

```
ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin-left:8%;
margin-right: 8%;
padding-left: 0;
padding-right: 0;
// overflow: hidden;  <---remove
height: 48px;         // <---add
background-color: #f3f3f3;
}
```

If you don't, the ul defaults to as if it has:

```
height: auto;
```

Relevant [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5vuxf3j5/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the height of the `<ul>` element, so it won't expand with the dropdown.